# is it possible to select running balances

Tags: mysql

I would like to select month(yyyy-mm),opening,debit,credit,closing
from transactions group by month(yyyy-mm);

here is the transactions table

date,debit,credit

Is it posssible in mysql alone with out php?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you searched for "[mysql] running balances" here? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @ken White Yes sir. I did. most of them suggested to do it in php. I am looking for a mysql only solution. thanks for asking.

Comment: You missed my point. :-) There's no indication in your question that you've tried or done anything to solve this yourself, and "Is this possible?" is not an answerable question here. I answered that ("Yes, it's possible"), and that's entirely sufficient to answer the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use variables, as in:

```
select `date`, debit, credit, (@bal := credit - debit) as bal
from transaction t cross join
     (select @bal := 0) const
order by `date`;
```

You can then use this for aggregation or whatever you want to do.